# Can a matter enter do work without being consumed up?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, particle-physics, physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

I had a tricky question in mind. So, I wanted to use the example of Catalysts (In chemical reactions) as an example. It's said that when catalysts enter a chemical reaction, they're *Never* consumed up. Is that possible? I mean, when catalysts do there **work**, they lose energy and probably heat. How can it get out of a chemical reaction without being consumed up?
In terms of physics, in general, anything that enters a reaction, or transfers energy, did any kind of work is in a way or another consumed up?
I'm sorry if my question is not clear, if it's not please tell me.
Thanks everybody!

Comment: No, a catalyst does not do work - it only offers a place for a reaction to happen differently (appropriate surface structure for example). It just sits there.

Comment: Please indicate what's not clear from a review of [Catalysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalysis).

Comment: I do have to say that this question looks at things in a way I'd never thought of... Indeed, "how can a catalyst enable a reaction without 'doing any _work_'?" :)

Comment: I agree with @paulgarrett that this is an interesting question and should not be closed. OK, let it be rephrased by asking instead about work as to how the catalysts's internal energy, does that change during a catalyzed reaction? Or if not its internal energy does its chemical potential versus surface tension, or entropy versus surface area change while keeping its internal energy constant, etc.

Comment: Well, what does "used up" mean in this context? If it means that the catalysis is a *reagent* and therefore gets "used up" by actually changing its chemical structure, then it's not "used up".  That's what I think of when people say catalysts aren't "used up", but that still allows *physical* and *thermodynamic* properties to change, i.e., the energy could change while the chemical structure of the catalyst stays the same.

Comment: Catalysts actually can be used up, just not chemically. E.g. https://technology.matthey.com/article/4/4/122-126/